# Add more apps buttons to my game?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[example :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3RhD.png)

I want something just like The example

here is my Buttons code :
I want to remove help button and add buttons to apps in google play market

Can you help me with this please : it is a java file

As I said I want something that list 3 of my games just like the screenshot

I already searched for examples but it doesnt work fr me

```
// buttons
    CCMenuItemImage play = CCMenuItemImage.item("menu/play1.png", "menu/play2.png", this, "onPlay");
    play.setAnchorPoint(1, 0);
    play.setPosition(G.width, 0);

    CCMenuItemToggle sound = CCMenuItemToggle.item(this, "onSound",
        CCMenuItemImage.item("menu/sound_off.png", "menu/sound_off.png"),
        CCMenuItemImage.item("menu/sound_on.png", "menu/sound_on.png"));
    sound.setSelectedIndex(G.sound?1:0);
    sound.setPosition(G.width*0.4f, 70);

    CCMenuItemToggle music = CCMenuItemToggle.item(this, "onMusic",
        CCMenuItemImage.item("menu/music_off.png", "menu/music_off.png"),
        CCMenuItemImage.item("menu/music_on.png", "menu/music_on.png"));
    music.setSelectedIndex(G.music?1:0);
    music.setPosition(G.width*0.5f, 70);
    CCMenuItemImage help = CCMenuItemImage.item("menu/help1.png", "menu/help2.png", this, "onHelp");
    help.setPosition(G.width*0.6f, 70);

    CCMenu menu = CCMenu.menu(play, sound, music, help);
    menu.setPosition(0, 0);
    addChild(menu);

    setIsKeyEnabled(true);
}

public void onPlay(Object sender)
{
    if( G.sound ) G.soundClick.start();

    CCScene s = CCScene.node();
    s.addChild(new SelectLayer(false));
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(CCFadeTransition.transition(0.7f, s));
}

public void onSound(Object sender)
{
    if( G.sound ) G.soundClick.start();

    G.sound = !G.sound;
    SharedPreferences sp = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().getSharedPreferences("GameInfo", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor  et = sp.edit();
    et.putBoolean("sound", G.sound);
    et.commit();
}

public void onMusic(Object sender)
{
    if( G.sound ) G.soundClick.start();

    G.music = !G.music;
    SharedPreferences sp = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().getSharedPreferences("GameInfo", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor  et = sp.edit();
    et.putBoolean("music", G.music);
    et.commit();

    if (G.music)
    {
        G.bgSound.start();
    }
    else
    {
        G.bgSound.pause();
    }
}

public void onHelp(Object sender)
{
    if( G.sound ) G.soundClick.start();

    CCScene s = CCScene.node();
    s.addChild(new HelpLayer());
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(CCFadeTransition.transition(0.7f, s));
}

public boolean ccKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    r.gc();
    System.gc();
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I will , thank you Joe

Answer (score 0):

you can try this , it worked for me

```
final ImageButton mybutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton); 
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String str ="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ws.crandell.newspaperpuzzles";
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));

    }

});
```